# How can I make this table in LateX (Single column & Multi Column)?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

[image]

Can you please help me figure out how to make a single and multiple column table like the one in the picture?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Spanning

Comment: Take a look at the `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` commands.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below code may meets your requirement:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Main} &\multirow{2}{*}{Total}\\
\cline{2-4}
& 1 &2 &3 &\\
\hline
Text2 & & & &\\
\hline
Text3 & & & &\\
\hline
Text4 & & & &\\
\hline
Text5 & & & &\\
\hline
Text6 & & & &\\
\hline
Text7 & & & &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```