# How to produce a specific table in LaTeX?

Tags: multirow

I am trying to produce a specific table in LaTeX however I am struggling with how best to code it. Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

So far I have the following code, however I am unsure as to how to center the bus numbers:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} p{3cm} p{2cm} p{2cm}}
\hline
Bus Number & Route Number & Release Time & Bus Number & Route Number & Release Time \\ [0.5ex] \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{1} & 1 & 100 & \multirow{2}{*}{6} & 1 & 100 \\
                   & 2 & 100 &                    & 2 & 100 \\
                   & 3 & 100 &                    & 3 & 100 \\
                   & 4 & 100 &                    & 4 & 100 \\
                   \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{2} & 1 & 100 & \multirow{2}{*}{7} & 1 & 100 \\
                   & 2 & 100 &                    & 2 & 100 \\
                   & 3 & 100 &                    & 3 & 100 \\
                   & 4 & 100 &                    & 4 & 100 \\
                   \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{3} & 1 & 100 & \multirow{2}{*}{8} & 1 & 100 \\
                   & 2 & 100 &                    & 2 & 100 \\
                   & 3 & 100 &                    & 3 & 100 \\
                   & 4 & 100 &                    & 4 & 100 \\
                   \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{4} & 1 & 100 & \multirow{2}{*}{9} & 1 & 100 \\
                   & 2 & 100 &                    & 2 & 100 \\
                   & 3 & 100 &                    & 3 & 100 \\
                   & 4 & 100 &                    & 4 & 100 \\
                   \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{5} & 1 & 100 & \multirow{2}{*}{10} & 1 & 100 \\
                   & 2 & 100 &                    & 2 & 100 \\
                   & 3 & 100 &                    & 3 & 100 \\
                   & 4 & 100 &                    & 4 & 100 \\
                   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)!On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506054/how-can-i-make-this-table-in-latex-single-column-multi-column (also the comments with that question).

Comment: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Comment: If you already know about the `\multirow` command what is the problem? Please show us what you've got so far in a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what many people believe, vertically centering the bus number would introduce ambiguity in the interpretation of a table.

A value that applies to all following rows, until countermanded by another value is simply stated at the top row of the group. Adding horizontal rules may help (as in the example), but it's not even required.

Since there are two main groups, more space should be allotted between them

The headers can be shortened by using two rows.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{\hspace{4em}}ccc@{}}
\toprule
Bus & Route & Release & Bus & Route & Release \\
Number & Number & Time & Number & Number & Time \\
\midrule
1 & 1 & 100 &  6 & 1 & 100 \\
  & 2 & 100 &    & 2 & 100 \\
  & 3 & 100 &    & 3 & 100 \\
  & 4 & 100 &    & 4 & 100 \\
\midrule
2 & 1 & 100 &  7 & 1 & 100 \\
  & 2 & 100 &    & 2 & 100 \\
  & 3 & 100 &    & 3 & 100 \\
  & 4 & 100 &    & 4 & 100 \\
\midrule
3 & 1 & 100 &  8 & 1 & 100 \\
  & 2 & 100 &    & 2 & 100 \\
  & 3 & 100 &    & 3 & 100 \\
  & 4 & 100 &    & 4 & 100 \\
\midrule
4 & 1 & 100 &  9 & 1 & 100 \\
  & 2 & 100 &    & 2 & 100 \\
  & 3 & 100 &    & 3 & 100 \\
  & 4 & 100 &    & 4 & 100 \\
\midrule
5 & 1 & 100 & 10 & 1 & 100 \\
  & 2 & 100 &    & 2 & 100 \\
  & 3 & 100 &    & 3 & 100 \\
  & 4 & 100 &    & 4 & 100 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]